FlaUI - GetMainWindow(new UIA3Automation()) throws System.Exception - Could not find process with id
I am trying to automate certain actions with preinstalled apps in Windows (Notepad, Clock, Paint, ...). As a start, I took Notepad for the test script. But I am getting exception "Could not find process with id "

OS: Windows 11

Target Framework: .net9.0-windows

Test Framework: NUnit and FlaUI

Code:


// main - references
using FlaUI.Core.Tools;
using FlaUI.UIA3;
using Application = FlaUI.Core.Application;
using Window = FlaUI.Core.AutomationElements.Window;

// main props ---
public static Window MainWindow { get; set; }
public static Application AppDriver { get; set; }

// main code ---
string NotepadAppFromStore = "Microsoft.WindowsNotepad_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App";
Application.LaunchStoreApp (NotepadAppFromStore);
// string NotepadApp = @"C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe";
// Application.Launch (NotepadApp); // This too didn't work.

using (var automation = new UIA3Automation ()) { // UIA2Automation too didn't work
   var window = Retry.WhileNull (() =>
       MainWindow = AppDriver.GetMainWindow (automation),
       TimeSpan.FromSeconds (10)
   ).Result;
   Console.WriteLine (window.Title);
}


Notes:
I got the Notepad AppID by running Get-StartApps | Select-Object Name, AppID in PowerShell.
